# File permission error when installing Meteor in Docker

Tags: meteor, docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker (2 weeks) but I'm making good progress writing a Dockerfile for a Meteor installation.

Now I am seeing file permission errors with the last line. Honestly I think the wider problem is that I don't fully understand the Linux file-system and permissions; so I would be grateful for any pointers.

This is the error:

```
Meteor 1.5 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your 
convenience.
This may prompt for your password.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Couldn't write the launcher script. Please either:

  (1) Run the following as root:
        cp "/home/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.5.0/mt-
        os.linux.x86_64/scripts/admin/launch-meteor" /usr/bin/meteor
  (2) Add "$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
  (3) Rerun this command to try again.
```

This is the command I run with:

```
docker build --build-arg user_pass=user -t timebandit/meteor-1-5 --rm .
```

This is the section of Dockerfile I believe to be the problem:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

# update the system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl \
    sudo \
    apt-utils \
    locales \
    nano

# Set the locale
RUN sudo sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8 

# set the root password
# RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd

# create a user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user
RUN adduser user sudo
RUN echo 'user:user' | chpasswd

ENV HOME=/home
WORKDIR $HOME
# WORKDIR $HOME/user

# allow writes to the home directory
USER root
RUN chmod 777 /home

# install meteor
# RUN echo $user_pass | curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
#docker build --build-arg user_pass=user -t timebandit/meteor-1-5 --rm .
ARG user_pass
USER user
```

Any pointers you can give to improve my understanding of the root of the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use a metor base image
https://github.com/jshimko/meteor-launchpad

Comment: Could you suggest what is wrong with the Dockerfile above?

Comment: Can you link the full Dockerfile ? Apart from the multiple RUN instead of only one with && I can't see any big mistakes

Comment: @WassimDhif I can open a shell into the container and run the curl command for meteor no problem. The issue is it doesnt work from the Dockerfile

Comment: @WassimDhif Done :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the meteor install script asks for a user input, since you don't give it, the build step just fails.

Here:
`This may prompt for your password.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: I update the file just now, i might have had a slightly different line, this does not have a TTY message and I pass in the `user` password as a build argument.

Comment: The comment above was for you.

Comment: Are you sure that `echo $user_pass | curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`.
Can you check on your machine ?

Comment: Yes. This is what I am running `https://pastebin.com/RDMK546U` with this command `docker build --build-arg user_pass=user -t timebandit/meteor-1-5 --rm .`

Comment: In the end I have installed Meteor from within the terminal and committed the image: https://hub.docker.com/r/timebandit/meteor-1-5/

Comment: Ok, it's not the best way to do it though. I think you should check the MeteorD meteor image, it could help you.